# How to get rid of default Spree panel in login page?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, authentication, spree

I want to implement my own layout for login page(by using Spree), but I'm struggle with default panel which get everytime I want to login.

I made _login.html.erb partial page in views/spree/shared, and try to override Spree with my own html but still i get "Login as Existing Customer" default panel above all my work.

When inspect page to see from where it comes I get

```
<div class="container">
 ::before
  <div class="row" data-hook>
    ::before
    <div id="content" class="col-sm-12" data-hook>

      <div class="col-md-6 ">
        <div class="panel panel-default">
          <div class="panel-heading">
            <h3 class="panel-title">Login as Existing Customer</h3>
      </div>

      <div id="existing-customer" class="panel-body" data- 
        hook="login">

          <div class="text-center">
            or 
                <a href="/signup">Create a new account</a> |
                <a href="/password/recover">Forgot Password?</a>
          </div>
          <div data-hook="login_extras"></div>
       </div>
      </div>
     </div>
    </div>

  </div>
</div>
```

I cannot find this html anywhere

I'm using spree 3.0.0